# Fetch /POST request to Server: Empty array when receiving multipart/form-data;

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, digital-ocean, multer-s3

Im trying to upload an image (ReactJs) to my server (NodeJs+ Express+ multerJs) to digital Ocean.

Im using a POST Request with multipart/form-data;

I get a succesfull message from multerJs but I can see in the log on the server that the files: [] has an empty array. And that Digital Ocean didnt add any file of course.

When i do the same Post request with the form without handling the submission of the form ,everything is working and the Files array is not empty.the code above is working :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:3004/upload_image_test_4"   >    </form>
```

Client-Side React.js :

```
export default class Select_size extends React.Component {
on_form_submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const fileInput = this.state.file;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileInput);
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
             Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
        }
    };
    var url =
        this.state.action_link +
        '?url=' +
        this.state.id_user +
        '/' +
        this.state.id_draft +
        '&name=' +
        this.state.name_file;
    fetch(url, options);
};

onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] });
};

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
  files: [],
  };
this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }
render() {
    return (  
<form onSubmit={this.on_form_submit} enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="myImage" onChange={this.onChange} />
                    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>

  )}
```

}

Server-side (Node.js/ ExpressJs/Multer/Digital Ocean) :

```
  const express = require('express');
  const router = express.Router();
  const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  const aws = require('aws-sdk');
  const spacesEndpoint = new aws.Endpoint('fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com');
  const s3 = new aws.S3({
  endpoint: spacesEndpoint,
  accessKeyId: 'myID',
  secretAccessKey: 'MySecretKey'
  });
  const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'bucketName',
    acl: 'public-read',
    key: function(request, file, cb) {
        cb(null, urlBucket + name_image);
        }
   })
   }).array('upload', 1);

  router.post('/upload_image_test_4', function(request, response, next) {
  upload(request, response, function(error) {
    console.log(request, 'the request');
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return response.json(error, 'error');
    }
    console.log('File uploaded successfully.');
    return response.json('success its uploaded to digital ocean');
});

});
module.exports = router;
```

If anyone can help me with that ! (I already 'googled' insanely,,,)
Thanks !!

Comment: Can you create  postman sample that works?

Comment: yes with postman it works,,,,

Comment: Can you provide script by postman:https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Comment: Mistake, doesnt work with postman as well, a similar repository can be find here : https://github.com/nyinyi164/spaces-node-app    it will work with <form> upload but not with a post request made on axios or postman ,

Comment: Can you copy successful post details  over browser with form :   chrome dev network..

Comment: Yes of course, i couldnt add the details in the comment, here a pdf, thank you : https://storage1germany.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/9f54b16c69a77042b964423d4db9e3ac/52da9e3a467c62428b8058123a4cb80c/request%20with%20%3Cform%3E.pdf

Comment: And this is the details of the request with Postman : https://storage1germany.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/9f54b16c69a77042b964423d4db9e3ac/52da9e3a467c62428b8058123a4cb80c/request%20postman%20not%20working.pdf

Comment: can you click on view URL encoded in the request Form Data

Comment: I clicked on it in the postman detail request, but formData is showing 'Formadata(0)' and it basically emtpy, so it doestn show anything more.  But in the details of the working <form> data request, 'FormData' is not showing in the detail request,,, weird.

Comment: I found a solution that I added in my post, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***//EDIT I found a solution to my own question... on the github page dedicated to a bug related to Next.js :*** 
The file was not send to the request for some reasons.
I used axios in this way and its now working :

React-js :

```
    sendFile = (e) => {
      const data = new FormData();
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      data.append('avatar', file);
     axios
            .post('http://localhost:3004/upload_test_stack_2', data)
            .then(console.log)
          .catch(console.error);  

      }
```

The server side (nodeJs) :

```
const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'My Bucket',
    acl: 'public-read',
    key: function(request, file, cb) {


        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
    })

});

router.post('/upload_test_stack_2', upload.single('avatar'), (req, res) 
 =>      {

    console.log(req.file, 'The file appears here');
    return res.sendStatus(200);
      });
```

Comment: Thank you! This hint save my days after some days of research.

Answer (score 0):

Files from input are not an array but FileArray, try [...e.target.files][0]

Comment: i m getting the same results, unfortunately,,,

Answer (score 0):

Related to Event Pooling in React and async behavior of setState.

Modify onChange  handler:

Method 1:

Put the file to variable and set it in setState.

```
onChange = (e) => {

      const uploadFile = e.target.files[0] ;
      this.setState({ file: uploadFile  });
};
```

Method 2 with event.persist():

```
onChange = (e) => {
         e.persist();
         this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] });
    };
```